# Updating a pod that is not declared in podfile

Tags: cocoapods

I'm migrating a project from Swift 3 to Swift 4. There was a problem with **BrightFutures**, a pod that I didn't explicitly declare in my `Podfile`.

`BrightFutures` is listed as `5.2.0`, but the version I want is `6.0.0`. I'm struggling to find out how this pod is managed in the first place. My pod file has no declaration of it:

```
// Podfile
platform :ios, '9.2'
abstract_target 'Application' do

    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Spine', :git => 'https://github.com/kelvinlauKL/Spine.git'
    pod 'AlamofireImage'
    pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator'
    pod 'JSQDataSourcesKit'
    pod 'RDHCollectionViewGridLayout'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'PKHUD'
    pod 'KMPlaceholderTextView'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'SVPullToRefresh'

    target 'Pixhug Production' do
    end

    target 'Pixhug Staging' do
    end

    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
            end
        end
    end

end
```

The `Podfile.lock` lists the framework:

```
- BrightFutures (5.2.0):
  - Result (~> 3.2)
```

## My attempts

1. `pod update`
2. `pod install`
3. `sudo gem install cocoapods` -> `pod update`/`pod install`
4. Deleting the `BrightFutures` stuff in `Podfile.lock`, and then running `pod update`

## Further notes

I noticed that `BrightFutures` is being used by the `Spine` framework. I manually updated `Spine` (which uses Carthage), and made sure it builds in Swift 4. I dragged the `6.0.0` `BrightFutures` framework into `Spine`.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `Spine` library declared a dependency to `BrightFutures` in it's cocoapods podspec file:

```
s.dependency 'BrightFutures', ~> '5.2.0'
```

This was why `BrightFutures` wouldn't go beyond the current version. Removing the versioning parameter allowed for an update to the latest version.